# IntelliJ IDEA не видит классы и методы, находящиеся в одном модуле

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdk11

Работал над проектом на рабочем компе, всё было в порядке, залил изменения в Git и спокойно себе пошёл домой. Прихожу, стаскиваю с Git-a изменения, запускаю проект и получаю такое вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это при том, что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Invalidate cache and restart не помогает, переустановка IntelliJ - тоже. JDK 11.0.7 с официального сайта Oracle. Как это пофиксить?

**UPD**
pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>yevhenii</groupId>
    <artifactId>screenshooter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>screenshooter</name>
    <description>Application for taking screenshots from different websites</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.rgielen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-weaver-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.rgielen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>25.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
            <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.805</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.00</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**UPD 1**
Вот что выдаёт mvn package из консоли:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project screenshooter: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1220)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: Скачайте предыдущую версию и посмотрите сначала там.

Comment: Предыдущую версию Intellij?

Comment: Версию проекта которая работала

Comment: Перед тем как залить изменения, я запускал приложение, всё было в порядке.

Comment: Ну перед уходом тоже я так понимаю. Так вот вернитесь на шаг назад где якобы у вас все было хорошо

Comment: Не помогло. Откатился к предыдущей ветке

Comment: Создайте что нибудь новое и скомпилируйте. Отдельный проект я имею в виду.

Comment: Создал пустой mаven проект, в нём пакет и Main. Написал обычный Hello World и импортировал несколько классов - всё работает

Comment: В проекте используется maven или gradle?

Comment: Да, Maven используется (Spring проект)

Comment: Много неизвестных: файлы проекта в git хранятся? используете именно файлы проекта или директорию `.idea`? как открывали проект: есть два варианта, которые еще делятся на кучу мелких, можно открыть как maven проект, а можно собственные файлы intellij. Далее, из командной строки `mvn package` проходит? Далее? в настройках проекта в intellij есть ли ошибки (показывает красные символы, знаки восклицательные если правильно помню)? Просмотрите разделы Project, Modules и Libraries, а в разделах - закладки.

Comment: Да и еще, эту дополнительную информацию, включая, и то что выше писали, т.е. что уже пробовали, нужно включать в текст вопроса. А не отвечать в комментариях.

Comment: Да, файлы проекта хранятся в git. Открывал просто: VCS -> Get from version control. `mvc package` не проходит, поскольку он не может провести `build`. Все ошибки, которые выдаёт - на скрине

Comment: Переименуйте директорию мавена .m2 на шо нить другое и создайте пустую .m2 кажется у вас конфликт версий в мавене

Comment: Если не проходит собственно сборка maven-ом, то intellij тут ни при чем. Какая-то проблема с конфигурацией проекта в мавен. Нужно показать pom.xml

Comment: Вы уверенны, что на рабочей машине сборка мавеном работала? Вполне возможно, что там intellij собирала напрямую без мавена.

Comment: Добавил pom.xml в текст вопроса.

Comment: Я не совсем уверен что проблема именно в maven, поскольку Build -> Build project выдаёт те же самые ошибки, что и compile с помощью maven

Comment: Кстати, вариант с переименованием .m2 не помог - зависимости подтянулись заново, но ошибки те же

Comment: Если не проходит сборка мавеном из командной строки (как Вы написали выше), то проблема именно в этом. `Build project` тоже использует мавен для сборки.

Comment: Добавил логи мавена в текст вопроса